# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function such that $2f(x+y)+f(x-y)=3f(x)+3f(y)+2xy \;\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $f'(0)=0$ then evaluate $f(5)+f'(5)$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, contest-math

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $2f(x+y)+f(x-y)=3f(x)+3f(y)+2xy \;\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $f'(0)=0$. Find the value of $f(5)+f'(5)$.

**Solution:**

Putting $x=y=0, f'(0)=0$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)+3f(h)+2xh}{2h}$

$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{2h}+\frac32\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}h+x$

$=\frac12f'(x)+x\implies f'(x)=2x\implies f(x)=x^2$

$\therefore f(5)+f'(5)=25+10=35$

**My doubt:**

I think when they expanded $f(x+h)$, it should have been $2f(x)$ instead of $f(x)$, i.e.,

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2f(x)-f(x-h)+3f(h)+2xh}{2h}$

But now I don't know what to do with the extra $f(x)$.

Comment: You are right. It is probably a typo in the equation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is correct. Since
$$2f(x+h)=3f(x)-f(x-h)+3f(h)+2xh,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
f(x+h)-f(x)&=\frac{2f(x+h)-\color{red}{2}f(x)}{2}\\
&=\frac{3f(x)-f(x-h)+3f(h)+2xh-\color{red}{2}f(x)}{2}\\
&=\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)+3f(h)+2xh}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach without needing to use derivatives.

First, put $x=y=0$, so that you get $f(0)=0$. Then put $x=y$ to get $$2f(2x)+f(0) = 6f(x)+2x^2 \implies f(2x)=3f(x)+x^2$$
Then put $y=-x$ to get $$2f(0)+f(2x) =3f(x)+3f(-x)-2x^2 \implies f(2x) =3f(x)+3f(-x)-2x^2$$

Equate both values of $f(2x)$ to get $f(-x)=x^2$. Then put $x \to -x$ so that $$f(x)=x^2$$

So $f(5)+f'(5) = 25 + 10 = 35$.